# Return java.io.File object from NodeRef in Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco

Is there any easy way to return File object from NodeRef? I'm converting nodes to temporary files and it works but it doesn't seem to be very practical. Here is my code:

```
public File getTempCopyAsFile() throws IOException{
    File tempFile = TempFileProvider.createTempFile("temp_"+this.getDocName(), this.getDocExtension());
    try (InputStream is = this.getReader().getContentInputStream()){
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, tempFile);
    } 
    return tempFile;
}

public ContentReader getReader() {
    return contentService.getReader(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);
}

public String getName() {
    return (String) nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_NAME);
}

public String getDocExtension() {
    return "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(this.getName());
}

public String getDocName() {
    return FilenameUtils.removeExtension(this.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to [use ContentService to get a ContentReader](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/ContentService.html#getReader-org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef-org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName-) for the node. Once you have that, call [ContentReader.getContent(File)](https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/content/AbstractContentReader.html#getContent-java.io.File-), which from the javadocs:

> Gets content from the repository direct to file
>
> All resources will be closed automatically.
>
> Parameters:
>      file - the file to write the content to - it will be overwritten

While the content will be stored somewhere on disk within the content repo, accessing the raw file isn't recommended. The safe way is to create a Temp file, then have `ContentReader` send the contents of the node into it

Comment: Ya, this is what I'm doing.

Comment: Nope, it isn't. You're messing around with the inputstream, much easier to have Alfresco stream it direct to the file for you